# Как передавать состояние между виджетами, расположенных в разных routes

Tags: flutter, dart

Написал приложение, которое должно:

1. Отображать список Employee из базы данных;
2. Добавлять новых Employee в базу данных(в другом окне).

Я понимаю, как изменять состояния виджетов, если произошли изменения в пределах ЭТОГО же окна. Но что, если изменения произошли во втором окне, а отобразить эти изменения требуется в первом?
Код ниже решал бы мою проблему... Только если его расположить выше моих routes, он перестает отрабатывать как надо.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Employee>>(
          future: DBProvider.db.getEmployees(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Employee>> snapshot) 
          { return ... ; }
)
```

Свой код не выкладываю, так как мой вопрос сейчас больше на понимание. Какие есть способы для решения конкретно моей задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Создаешь просто переменную контроллера потока
StreamController<List<Employee>> gStreamController;

// Далее идут какие-то твои классы в которых ты получаешь данные из базы данных
class DBProvider {
  static DbProv db;
}

class DbProv {
  getEmployees() {
    //
    Employee someEmployee1 = Employee();
    Employee someEmployee2 = Employee();
    Employee someEmployee3 = Employee();
    Employee someEmployee4 = Employee();
    // Допустим тут ты получил свои данные (список [Employee] элементов)
    List<Employee> data = [
      someEmployee1,
      someEmployee2,
      someEmployee3,
      someEmployee4,
    ];
    //!!! И вот самое интересное!!!))) Именно в этом местте отправляешь весь свой список данных на поток [gStreamController], который будет перехвачен в потоковом строителе
    // в этом месте [stream: gStreamController.stream,]
    gStreamController.add(data);
  }
}

class Employee {}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  // перезаписываем внутреннюю функцию [didChangeDependencies()] в [StatefulWidget]
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async{
    // Тут (на всякий случай проверяем закрытие контролера)
   await gStreamController?.close();
   // Тут его создаем.
    gStreamController = StreamController();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

// перезаписываем внутреннюю функцию [dispose()] в [StatefulWidget]
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Тут закрываем поток (когда происходит закрытие вашего виджета)
    gStreamController?.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Employee>>(
        //!!! Место перехвата данных которые были отправлены в строке [gStreamController.add(data);]
        stream: gStreamController.stream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Employee>> snapshot) {
          List<Employee> data = snapshot.data;
          // Из [data] уже строить то отображение которое думал
          return ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Text('${data[index]}');
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Лучше добавить этот пример в предыдущий ответ, отредактировав его.

Answer (score 2):

Вот коротенький пример того как решить данную проблему

```
// Создаешь контроллер потока
StreamController<List<Employee>> gStreamController = StreamController();

// Далее идут какие-то твои классы в которых ты получаешь данные из базы данных
class DBProvider {
  static DbProv db;
}

class DbProv {
  getEmployees() {
    //
    Employee someEmployee1 = Employee();
    Employee someEmployee2 = Employee();
    Employee someEmployee3 = Employee();
    Employee someEmployee4 = Employee();
    // Допустим тут ты получил свои данные (список [Employee] элементов)
    List<Employee> data = [
      someEmployee1,
      someEmployee2,
      someEmployee3,
      someEmployee4,
    ];
    //!!! И вот самое интересное!!!))) Именно в этом местте отправляешь весь свой список данных на поток [gStreamController], который будет перехвачен в потоковом строителе 
    // в этом месте [stream: gStreamController.stream,]
    gStreamController.add(data);
  }
}

class Employee {}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Employee>>(
      //!!! Место перехвата данных которые были отправлены в строке [gStreamController.add(data);]
        stream: gStreamController.stream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Employee>> snapshot) {
          List<Employee> data = snapshot.data;
          // Из [data] уже строить то отображение которое думал
          return ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Text('${data[index]}');
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Все работает, большое спасибо. Пока у меня контроллер потока является публичной переменной... Можно ли ее во что-то обернуть/передавать, ведь может возникнуть ситуация, что таких контроллеров у меня может быть несколько...

Comment: То есть, глобальной переменной(то есть, ее жизненный цикл == работы программы)

Comment: да используй для этого StatefulWidget.

Сейчас ниже пример с ним брошу.